# How to use WHERE and INNER JOIN together

Tags: sql

### Selected name, surname and sum of costs but it doesn't work. Is using WHERE possible here?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad, soyad, SUM(gunluk_ucret) AS toplam
FROM Kart as k
INNER JOIN musteri ON k.TCNO=musteri.TCNO 
INNER JOIN ekipman ON k.ekipman_id=ekipman.ekipman_id
GROUP BY ad,soyad,gunluk_ucret;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, the `group by` keys and `select` keys are not consistent.  Perhaps that is the problem you are asking about:

```
SELECT ad, soyad, SUM(gunluk_ucret) AS toplam
FROM Kart k INNER JOIN
     musteri m
     ON k.TCNO = m.TCNO INNER JOIN
     ekipman e
     ON k.ekipman_id = e.ekipman_id
GROUP BY ad, soyad;
```

You should qualify all column references in the query.  I don't know what tables the columns come from, so I cannot make any suggests there.